# Accessing sibling functions within a self-executing function

Tags: javascript, function

I feel like I'm making a really simple error here. Essentially, I'm just trying to access a function from another function within a self-executing function. Is there any reason why `printConfirmation` isn't being called? It seems that `eventHandlers` isn't properly working either.

```
(function(){

  var targetZone = document.getElementById('target-zone');

  var eventHandlers = function(){
    targetZone.addEventListener('click', printConfirmation); 
  };

  var printConfirmation = function(){
    targetZone = targetZone.classList;
    targetZone.add('clicked');
  }; 

})();
```

Comment: you aren't calling `eventHandlers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hoisting issue, change to function declarations instead of function expressions and it will work:

```
(function(){

  var targetZone = document.getElementById('target-zone');

  function eventHandlers(){
    targetZone.addEventListener('click', printConfirmation); 
  }

  function printConfirmation(){
    targetZone = targetZone.classList;
    targetZone.add('clicked');
  }

  eventHandlers();
})();
```

Edit: Also, as Daniel pointed out, you need to actually call `eventHandlers()`

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it still a hoisting issue though if I call `eventHandlers` as @daniel-a-white pointed out and it executes?

Comment: Function expressions do not get hoisted the same way that function declarations do. There may be some browsers that allow it, but generally speaking you should only call function expressions after they have been defined.

Comment: Since you call `eventHandlers()` at the end of that self-executing function scope, it should work equally well without turning function expressions into declarations, right?